# Using a FOR loop for an array of elements selected by class, and calling functions on each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am attempting to loop over the `whateverDiv`and find the offset of each element. I am getting the error message `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`, I suspect because `.offset()` cannot be called on the element. This brings me to the question of how I can call functions, such as `.offset()` and `.is(":hover")` on elements in an array like this.

```
whateverDiv  = document.getElementsByClassName('whatever')
//RETURNS SOMETHING LIKE [<img src=​"http:​/​/​www.whateversource.jpg">​,<img src=​"http:​/​/​www.whateversource2.jpg">​]
for (i in whateverDiv){
    console.log(whateverDiv[i].offset())
}
```

Comment: `whateverDiv[i]` is a DOM element, not a jQuery collection, and has no `.offset()` method - you'd need `$()` to wrap it. Why not actually *use* jQuery when you include it?

Comment: Use `for in` for iterating the keys of an object, and a standard `for` for iterating an array.

Comment: I was trying to do the same for loop, only having `whateverDiv  = $('.whatever');` and got the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have jquery included

```
whateverDiv  = document.getElementsByClassName('whatever')
//RETURNS SOMETHING LIKE [<img src=​"http:​/​/​www.whateversource.jpg">​,<img src=​"http:​/​/​www.whateversource2.jpg">​]
for (i in whateverDiv){
    var $div = $(whateverDiv[i])
    console.log($div.offset())
}
```

And as others mentioned, you shouldn't use `for in`, but rather the standard `for` construction. However, if you're using jQuery already you might as well drink the koolaide and use their .each

http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$(".whatever").each(function() {
  console.log( $(this).offset() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You've coded your loop with a combination of both types of `for` loop.

```
for (i in whateverDiv) {
    // 'i' is each element
}
```

vs.

```
for (var i = 0; i < whateverDiv.length; i++) {
    // 'i' can be used as an index of the 'whateverDiv' collection
}
```

However, as has been stated in the comments, your best bet is to use all jQuery, since the objects inside the loop will still need to be converted to a jQuery object to use those functions.

```
$('.whateverDiv').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).offset());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jQuery loop:

```js
 $('.whatever').each(function(index, value) {
    console.log('Item: ' + index + ' - element: ' + $(value).text());
   // you could call a function like this on each element:
   // yourFunction($(value));
   // or a function of the jQuery element -> $(value).offset();    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="whatever">
  item one
</div>
<div class="whatever">
  item two
</div>
<div class="whatever">
  item three
</div>
<div class="whatever">
  item four
</div>
<div class="whatever">
  item five
</div>
```